# Parsing JSON with Bash jq Issue

Tags: json, bash, jq

Using bash JQ parser, Im trying parse the fields from a cURL `JSON` response.

In file `'a.json'` has 4 'hash' values and `'b.json'` has 5 'hash' values. Based on the assumption that my results will be similar to `"a.json"` I wrote a parser for it.

```
#jq -r '.info[].hashes[0].value','.info[].hashes[1].value','.info[].hashes[2].value','.info[].hashes[3].value' a.json
```

Sample JSON files

```
#a.json

{
"info": {
                "file": {
                    "Score": 4.01207390507143,
                    "file_subtype": "None",
                    "file_type": "EXE",
                    "hashes": [
                        {
                            "name": "A",
                            "value": "7e5dcd8ffdfa8d726ecbdd3c69e18230"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "B",
                            "value": "3c6781d16dc26baf6422bb24d1cd0f650e451b99"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "C",
                            "value": "3c6781d16dc26baf6422bb24d1cd0f650e451b99"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "D",
                            "value": "c25561f3246ef188467a47971821bab93934842a1e2a48910db9768a2f66e828"
                        }
                    ],
                    "size": 1912
          }
}
}



 #b.json
{
"info": {
                "file": {
                    "Score": 4,
                    "file_subtype": "None",
                    "file_type": "Image",
                    "hashes": [
                      {
                            "name": "A",
                            "value": "f34d5f2d4577ed6d9ceec516c1f5a744"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "B",
                            "value": "66031dad95dfe6ad10b35f06c4342faa"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "C",
                            "value": "9df25fa4e379837e42aaf6d05d92012018d4b659"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "D",
                            "value": "4a51cc531082d216a3cf292f4c39869b462bf6aa"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "E",
                            "value": "e445f412f92b25f3343d5f7adc3c94bdc950601521d5b91e7ce77c21a18259c9"
                        }
                    ],
                    "size": 500
          }
}
}
```

But some times the results will be like "b.json" too and have 5 fields .  when i'm trying to parse with the JQ command that i have written , Will give me only 4 fields and missing out the last value of "E".

```
#jq -r '.info[].hashes[0].value','.info[].hashes[1].value','.info[].hashes[2].value','.info[].hashes[3].value' b.json

Result : 

f34d5f2d4577ed6d9ceec516c1f5a744
66031dad95dfe6ad10b35f06c4342faa
9df25fa4e379837e42aaf6d05d92012018d4b659
4a51cc531082d216a3cf292f4c39869b462bf6aa
```

Now , How can we select only the hash values from desired 'name'.

Example : If we want to select only hash values of string 'names' B,C,E in any JSON files using JQ  ?

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the values with this:

```
jq -r '.info.file.hashes[] | .value' *.json
```

Suppose you need only the values where name == "B"

```
jq -r '.info.file.hashes[] | select(.name == "B") | .value'
```

Suppose you need only the values where name == "B" *or* "C"

```
jq -r '.info.file.hashes[] | select(.name | in({"B":1,"C":1})) | .value'
```

The "in" function checks if the passed-in string is a key in the given object. The values of `{"B":1,"C":1}` are arbitrary. Ref: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#in

Comment: Glen : Thanks , This will give me all values exactly. If i need get the "values" from particular "name" in all the JSON files , How can i do that ?

Comment: Glen : Thanks Glean. Select is the option i was looking. Now got it

Answer (score 0):

> How can we select only the hash values from desired 'name'. Example : If we want to select only hash values of string 'names' B,C,E in any JSON files using JQ ?

Here is a solution which uses [indices](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#indices(s))

```
  .info.file.hashes
| (map(.name) | [ indices($names[]) | .[] ]) as $found
| .[ $found[] ]
| .value
```

If this filter is in `filter.jq` and the sample data in `a.json` and `b.json` then

```
jq -M -r --argjson names '["B","C","E"]' -f filter.jq a.json b.json
```

produces

```
3c6781d16dc26baf6422bb24d1cd0f650e451b99
3c6781d16dc26baf6422bb24d1cd0f650e451b99
66031dad95dfe6ad10b35f06c4342faa
9df25fa4e379837e42aaf6d05d92012018d4b659
e445f412f92b25f3343d5f7adc3c94bdc950601521d5b91e7ce77c21a18259c9
```

note the first hash is duplicated in the sample data.  If that is a problem it can easily be handled with [unique](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#unique,unique_by(path_exp)) or other post-processing.